# Intersection of two circular arcs with same center

Tags: geometry, circles

How do you programmatically get intersection points of 2 circles given the same centers, radii, and sweep angle? The 2 circles are not exactly one whole circle.

[image]

I have an equation for each circle:

(x<sub>1</sub>-h<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>1</sub>-k<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = r<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>
(x<sub>2</sub>-h<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (y<sub>2</sub>-k<sub>2</sub>)<sup>2</sup> = r<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>

Please help thanks.

Comment: How do you know the "sweep angle" of each circular arc (that is the correct name for the figure), and what format is it in? If the arcs are in the same circle, $h_1=h_2$, $k_1=k_2$, and $r_1=r_2$, so why do you have different constant names?

Comment: the sweep angle for each circular arc is a given. they differ in starting points and end points. If only I can get the points they have in common....

Comment: @tjvg1991 Do you know the start points and end points? If so, what format are those points in? That is, do you know their coordinates, or their angular positions, or what? Obviously if you don't know the start and end points, the problem is impossible.

Comment: Without a description of how Azimuth is measured the question is not well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is with parametric equations and polar points instead of Cartesian form. Here is a [dynamic example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lw1ho0ohys).

This is not the place for an excessive tutorial on precalculus material, but basically, here is what is going on there:

We can define an equation for a circle, centered at the origin, with a given radius $r$, and a given radian angle sweep $t$ from $t_0$ to $t_1$ as

\begin{align*}
x(t)&=r\cos(t) \\
y(t)&=r\sin(t), \, t_0\leq t \leq t_1.
\end{align*}

So simply define two of these, with the same radius $r$, but different angular sweeps over $t$. Now in the example I made above, If you know the angular sweep, it is quite simple. I chose to make one circle sweep radian angle $t$ over $1 \leq t \leq 3.5$, while the other circle sweeps over $2.5 \leq t \leq 5$.

Thus the intersection of these two sets is the start and end points of where these circles meet, those being the polar points, 
$$\left(r\cos \left(2.5\right),\space r\sin \left(2.5\right)\right)$$

and

$$\left(r\cos \left(3.5\right),\space r\sin \left(3.5\right)\right).$$

Finally, we can parametrically define the entire intersection of these two circle segment examples with a third circle segment, that being in this case,

\begin{align*}
x(t)&=r\cos(t) \\
y(t)&=r\sin(t), \, 2.5\leq t \leq 3.5.
\end{align*}

Conversion from Cartesian to polar, and back is quite a simple task that I am sure you can sort out as needs be. Programmatically, this seems like one sensible way to work. It is at least the first thing that comes to my mind.